# openssl SubjectDN parameter, abbreviaton of argument keys and how to add extra ones

Tags: openssl, x.509

openssl command allows to create x509 certificates, and to add subjectDN using the -subj parameter.
The parameter accepts a string of slash-delimited values in the form of:

```
"/UPPERCASE_ABBREVIATED_KEY=VALUE/.../"
```

i.e.

```
"/C=IT/ST=Italy/L=Milan/O=myservice/CN=localhost"
```

I could not find a complete list of the allowed keys, and I need to create a certificate with the following extentions:

- organizationName       (O)
- commonName             (CN)
- uri                    (?!)
- organizationIdentifier (?!)
- countryName            (C)
- localityName           (L)

of which uri and organizationIdentifier I have no clue on how to include.
to my knowledge (fairly limited, i am just starting in the digital signature world), the values this parameter can incorporate are:

- Country Name (C)
- State or province (ST)
- Locality (L)
- Organization Name (O)
- Organizational Unit Name (...)
- Common Name (CN)
- Email Address (...)

Is there a place where I can find the complete list of possibile attributes and their abbreviation?
or maybe something other than openssl that allows to build the certificate ?
Is it possible that to add the extra fields (uri, OrganizationIdentifier) the addtext argument must be used?
Thank you in advance for your time and understending.
Best regards

Answer (score 1):

In an [X.500 distinguished name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol#Directory_structure) **the "keys" represent [Object Identifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_identifier) abbreviated OIDs**. This includes the Subject and Issuer names in an X.509 certificate and also the Subject name in a PKCS10 CSR, and quite a few other things.

> I could not find a complete list of the allowed keys.

There is no *complete* list. The OID assignment scheme allows unlimited hierarchical expansion -- this is like asking for a complete list of all URLs in the world. OpenSSL *predefines* a fixed but large set of OIDs that have been standardized or at least widely used; see the header `obj_mac.h` on your system if you have a 'development' version of OpenSSL installed (i.e. headers and libraries suitable for compiling your own code, rather than merely running precompiled code) or if you have source code the `crypto/objects.txt` file from which `obj_mac.h` is derived [or in the repository](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/objects/objects.txt). In the former file the LN_ string is the 'long name' and SN_ is the 'short name' or abbreviation, if different. In the latter file these are just columns on one line, with the short name first or empty to indicate there is no distinct abbreviation.
For example `CN` is the short name and `commonName` the long name for the OID 'X509 3' which, using other definitions in the file, expands to the actual OID 2.5.4.3.

If you -- or (more likely) someone or something you are interoperating with -- needs an OID outside of OpenSSL's predefined set, either because it's standard but rare and/or new, or because it's not standard at all, then you can still use it in OpenSSL by defining it in your configuration file; see the `oid_file` and `oid_section` items in the [man page for `req`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/req.html#CONFIGURATION-FILE-FORMAT) or [for `ca`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/ca.html#CONFIGURATION-FILE-OPTIONS) or the [generic config](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man5/config.html#ASN1-Object-Configuration-Module) for other commands like `x509`.

*Typically* the OIDs defined *in X.509*, and those defined for X.509 in PKCS9 (such as emailAddress), are commonly used in X.509 subjects, but technically any OID can be.
As you can see in the predefined list(s), there is an X509-scope OID for long name `organizationIdentifier` with no different short name -- this MAY be what your specifier wants, although it may not. There is no such obviously applicable OID for a URI, or URL; ask them to be precise about what they want, or to give/show you an example that *shows* precisely what they want.

> I need to create a certificate with the following extentions:
> Is it possible ... the addtext argument must be used? [You mean `-addext` in `req`]

**These are not extensions.** X.509 certificates have name fields containing **attributes**, which are one thing and the thing you want, and separately (but similarly identified by OIDs) they have extensions, which are a completely different thing that you do NOT want. Or at least not for this purpose; as you proceed you *may* find you also want extensions for something completely different that the specifier 'forgot'.

Comment: thank you for the very informative and detailed answer. Assuming the OID organizationIdentifier of x509 namespace is what i'm after, how would i insert it in my certificate using the openssl command ? Just as another parameter of the -subj string? "/.../objectIdentifier=.../..."?

Comment: dark: yes. Or you can add it to the set of values or prompts in the config file and use that, but that's more work.